# Add comment not working on mobile opera mini

Tags: bug

When I use Opera mini 4.5 on mobile view (not full site) and then click "add comment" to respond to a question reply, it looks like nothing happens at all, the small reply box doesn't show up.

Comment: Adding comments seemed broken for me also in Opera (regular, not mobile), as of thirty minutes ago. Now it seems I can comment again - I notice that _sometimes_ the `enter at least 15 characters` notice shows up below, and sometimes it doesn't. This time it showed, so hopefully I can add this.